# Expandable onchild Method

Tags: android, string, listview, android-intent, expandablelistview

My app working but I am facing a problem. When I click first header child its opening google. But when I click second header its opening again Google ! It have to open yahoo when I click second header ? I wrote but its working for one everytime :( how can I fix this ?

```
public class osym extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
ExpandableListView expListView2;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.expand);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    expListView2 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    expListView2.setAdapter(listAdapter);




    final ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();         
    links.add("http://www.google.com"); // i got problem here.

    final ArrayList<String> links2 = new ArrayList<String>();         
    links2.add("http://www.yahoo.com"); // when i click second list of child.it must open yahoo but it opening google :( ? 


    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

             if(childPosition == 0)
            {

                 Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
                    int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));  // send the url here
                    startActivity(int0);
                    finish();
            }
         if(childPosition == 1)
        {

             Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
                int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));  // send the url here
                startActivity(int0);
                finish();
        }

         if(childPosition == 2)
        {

             Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
                int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));  // send the url here
                startActivity(int0);
                finish();
        }
         if(childPosition == 3)
        {

             Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
                int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));  // send the url here
                startActivity(int0);
                finish();
        }
     if(childPosition == 4)
        {

             Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
                int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));  // send the url here
                startActivity(int0);
                finish();
        }

     if(childPosition == 5)
        {

             Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
                int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));  // send the url here
                startActivity(int0);
                finish();
        }

    return false;

        }
    });
}


private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Geometri Çıkmış Sorular");
    listDataHeader.add("Matematik Çıkmış Sorular");


    // Adding child data
    List<String> geo = new ArrayList<String>();
    geo.add("2009 Öss Geometri Çözümler");



    List<String> mat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    mat1.add("Polinomlar");






    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), geo); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), mat1);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see here, you have not attached the yahoo url to your first Array List name links, what you are doing you are passing the yahoo into second array list named links2 and not using that arraylist. So change like this

```
final ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();         
    links.add("http://www.google.com"); 
    links.add("http://www.yahoo.com");


expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

             if(childPosition == 0)
            {

            Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
             int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));  // refernce for google
                    startActivity(int0);
                    finish();
            }
         if(childPosition == 1)
        {

             Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
                int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));  // refernce for yahho
                startActivity(int0);
                finish();
        }
```

**Edit:** If you want to move parent to parent list item then use this.

```
  if(childPosition == 0 && groupPosition==0)
        {

             Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),webplayer.class);
                int0.putExtra("url", links.get(childPosition));
                startActivity(int0);
                finish();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help I ran it for 2 days.

Comment: Stop adding links to your own site in the questions you answer.

Comment: Sorry for that, will not do this in future. Thanks RobH for good point out.